# Detecting activity over an iFrame and then running a function

Tags: iframe

This topic has been covered a few times but there is no clear solution using Javascript. All responses were quite nebulous. Please help me out as there hasn't been a straightforward answer anywhere that I could find on any site.

I am trying to execute a function when any click occurs within an iframe window. Specifically, a click on a hyperlink on page displayed within the iframe. However just being able to have any click within an iframe trigger a function is enough for me.

I have a function Show() that I would like to run when an iframe is clicked. So basically a link is automatically hidden and when the first link is clicked it is shown. When the "click to hide" link that shows up is clicked, the "click to hide" link is hidden. I want the "click to hide" link to show up when someone clicks within the iframe. I need it to run the function every time a click occurs within the iframe. Thanks.

A user came up with a solution using a div which technically is a solution but it has some problems that I will explain below:

Non-tweaked Code:

```html
<html>
  <head>


  <title>StackOverflow Example</title>


  <style>
  .visible {visibility: visible}
  .hidden {visibility: hidden}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var visible_link = true;
  function Hide() {
      document.getElementById("my_div").className = "hidden";
      document.getElementById("my_button").value = "SHOW";
  }
  function Show() {

   
      document.getElementById("my_div").className = "visible";
      document.getElementById("my_button").value = "HIDE";
    
    
  }
 
  </script>


  </head>



  <body>

<center>


<iframe src="http://www.google.com" height=549 width=100% frameborder=0 name = "hello"></iframe>

<a href="http://www.google.com" target = "hello" onclick = "Show();">click to show below link</a>

    <div id="my_div" class="hidden">
      <a href="http://www.google.com" target="hello" onclick = "Hide();" >click me to hide</a>
    </div>


    
</center>  

</body>

</html>
```

The addition of a div allows the link to appear when the iframe area is clicked (just where the div is as you can see -- unfortunately I think I am just clicking the div and nothing on the iframe's page under it is clickable).

However, I am having three problems.

1) How can the div take up the full width of the window (I tried adding 100% to the width value under #cover).

2) When the div covers all of the iframe, the webpage within the iframe is not clickable.

3) The div is not transparent.

Tweaked Code:

```html
<html>
  <head>


  <title>StackOverflow Example</title>


  <style>
  .visible {visibility: visible}
  .hidden {visibility: hidden}
#cover {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* added for example */
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var visible_link = true;
  function Hide() {
      document.getElementById("my_div").className = "hidden";
      document.getElementById("my_button").value = "SHOW";
  }
  function Show() {

   
      document.getElementById("my_div").className = "visible";
      document.getElementById("my_button").value = "HIDE";
    
    
  }
 
  </script>


  </head>



  <body>

<center>

<div id="cover" onclick="Show();"></div>
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" height=549 width=100% frameborder=0 name = "hello"></iframe>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target = "hello" onclick = "Show();">links</a>

    <div id="my_div" class="hidden">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="hello" onclick = "Hide();" ><-</a>
    </div>


    
</center>  

</body>

</html>
```

If someone can edit the above code and have the div take up all of the width while being transparent with the iframe's webpage being entirely clickable - I would be very appreciative and happy.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It's not perfect but I figured out that I don't really need to it to detect every iframe click and this is good enough. I originally wanted to make a back button appear if a link within the page that is within the iframe was clicked (which would return the user to the main page within the iframe where they started). Obviously they may click randomly and not hit a hyperlink and the back link would pop up for no reason (while they are still on the main page). That's fine I guess but if someone knows of a better solution let me know. Most people would just hit a link to begin with as the page only has hyperlink interaction I presume.

I hope my working code below helps people who are exploring this topic in the future.

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>


<title>StackOverflow Example</title>


<style>
.visible {visibility: visible}
.hidden {visibility: hidden}

}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var visible_link = true;

var inIframe = false;
function Hide() {
document.getElementById("my_div").className = "hidden";
document.getElementById("my_button").value = "SHOW";
}
function Show() {


document.getElementById("my_div").className = "visible";
document.getElementById("my_button").value = "HIDE";


}


function checkClick() {
if (document.activeElement 
&& document.activeElement === document.getElementById("hello")) {
if (inIframe == false) {
Show();
inIframe = true;
}
} else
inIframe = false;
}
setInterval(checkClick, 200);

</script>


</head>



<body>

<center>

<div id="cover" onclick="Show();"></div>
<iframe src="http://w3schools.com" height=549 width=100% frameborder=0 name = "hello" id = "hello" style =""></iframe>

<a href="http://w3schools.com" target = "hello" onclick = "Show();">click to show link</a>

<div id="my_div" class="hidden">
<a href="http://w3schools.com" target="hello" onclick = "Hide();" >click to hide</a>
</div>



</center> 

</body>

</html>
```